# JPG or JPEG Texture in OPENGL

Tags: opengl, textures

In OpenGL you could read a BMP file and use it as texture. 
I know how to read a BMP file in OPENGL. 
I just want to know if is it the same thing with JPG or JPEG files? is OpenGL support those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL does **not** support BMP files. It just cares about raw image date as one-, two or threedimensional arrays of pixel data with up to 4 channels (and a set of different data types). OpenGL does not even know what a *file* is. And it can't load anything. If you need JPEG files, you have to load them via other means, like [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/) or some higher level image loading libraries or some of the other [image loading libraries](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Libraries).